# Semantic versioning in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, npm

From the solidity docs I have read that:

> The version pragma is used as follows: pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

> A source file with the line above does not compile with a compiler
> earlier than version 0.5.2, and it also does not work on a compiler
> starting from version 0.6.0 (this second condition is added by using
> ^). Because there will be no breaking changes until version 0.6.0, you
> can be sure that your code compiles the way you intended. The exact
> version of the compiler is not fixed, so that bugfix releases are
> still possible.

In npm it seems to be a bit different. From [this blog post](https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/) it says:

> So if you see `~1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest
> patch version such as `1.0.4`. If you see `^1.0.2` it means to install
> version `1.0.2` or the latest minor or patch version such as `1.1.0`.

Is semantic versioning in solidity different from that in npm or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question. Thanks to [this question and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67004296/9953550).

Before the major versioning gets to 1 i.e `0.x.x` the caret `^` and the tilde `~` act in the same way. Visit this site, [npm semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/), to experiment and learn more.